# The error that the other server returned was: 550 5.1.1

Tags: email

Help..what is going on? We recently launched a new website and redirected the domain. Now email doesn't work.

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 info@byfieldcac.org
```

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain byfieldcac.org by smtp.secureserver.net. [72.167.238.29].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.1.1  Recipient not found.  http://x.co/irbounce

Answer (score 0):

You have redirected the website but email service points to Godaddy email hosting smtp.secureserver.net(as per the bounce back) so make sure you have created this email address at your Godaddy email accounts manage interface. If you are not using Godaddy email hosting and want to use any other email server, you should change the MX record accordingly.